# Jenkins plugin Publish over SSH not transferring flles

Tags: git, bash, amazon-web-services, ssh, jenkins

After I created a new job and I get SUCCESS from log output I notice that I get

```
SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
Finished: SUCCESS
```

what is the process?
I create a .tgz in the build stage on the workspace directory:

```
cd ${WORKSPACE}/;
if [ -f composer.json ];
then 
/usr/bin/composer install;
fi
tar -zcvf ../${JOB_NAME}.tgz ./
```

then with the Publish over SSH plugin I want to move it to the deploy folder:
[image: jenkins config]

I checked in my workspace, the .tgz file exists there. Then I looked into my target, "deploy" folder has been created but the file didn't exist over there..

What should I do?

Comment: you are creating $JOB_NAME .tgz file one directory below $WORKSPACE. That's why - 0 files transferred.  Replace tar command line with "tar -cvzpf ${JOB_NAME}.tgz ." and see if it works. OR , change the value in the "Source files" box under "Transfers" section, to use "../${JOB_NAME}.tgz". If you need more details on SSH file transfer, turn verbose on, under "Advanced" button.

Comment: that's strange because in the other jobs its work well but thanks you you help me a lot to resolve the issue